# where to put a php file in cpanel which would serve my form in html

Tags: php, html, hosting, cpanel

I'm using Hostgator as my CPanel and a Domain. I created a website using html and in which I use a contact form on submit it goes to a php file and it sends me an email.

It works perfectly on amazon webserver but I don't know where to put my PHP files in hostgator cpanel. Should i install php config somewhere and put it there?

Thanks in advance.

```
Here is my php code
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$name = $_POST['inputUsername']; 
$email_address = $_POST['inputEmail']; 
$message = $_POST['inputContent']; 

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'krishnakumar4315@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('something@gmail.com', 'Krishna');

$mail->addAddress('something@outlook.com', 'Krishna');               // Name is optional

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Message From: '.$name;
$mail->Body    = $message ." <b>Email: </b>".$email_address;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
header('Location: http://www.krishdev.com');    

}
?>
```

Comment: Look for the public_html folder

Comment: Yes I did that I placed it in public_html>mydomain.com>myphpfile.php
But it is not working it throws this error
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: By default the server will load the index.html/php file. Try renaming the myphpfile.php file to index.php

Comment: Yes I tried it I changed it to index.php and also I changed it in my html form action to index.php But it still throws the same error

Comment: show the code of `myphpfile.php`

Comment: Kindly look at the question I had added it.

Comment: Okay thanks for your comments 
I found the answer I just wanna chat isSmtp to IsMail()